# how can I soft delete associate child rows when deleting the parent using sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

this is my loan model removed some properties to shorten it.

```
module.exports = (sequelize, type) => {
  return sequelize.define(
    "loan",
    {
      id: {
        type: type.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true,
      },
      userId: {
        type: type.INTEGER,
        required: true,
        allowNull: false,
      },
    },
    {
      underscored: false,
      paranoid: true,
    }
  );
};
```

this is loan payment model

```
module.exports = (sequelize, type) => {
  return sequelize.define(
    "loan_payment",
    {
      id: {
        type: type.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true,
      },
      loanId: {
        type: type.INTEGER,
        required: true,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      amount: {
        type: type.INTEGER,
        required: true,
        allowNull: false,
      },
    },
    {
      underscored: false,
      paranoid: true,
    }
  );
};
```

this is the association

```
Loan.hasMany(LoanPayment, {
  foreignKey: "loanId",
  onDelete: "CASCADE",
});
LoanPayment.belongsTo(Loan, {
  onDelete: "CASCADE",
});
```

Comment: CASCADE in sequelize association has minor effect. Most important is CASCADE in your db.